# What's the meaning of max ([max(A) max(B)]) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, neural-network, max

I have a part of a code of Neural Network in Matlab:

```
p = randint(a); 

p1 = p(1:10,:); 
p2 = p(11:20,:); 

d1 = max([max(p1(:,1)) max(p2(:,1))]);
d2 = max([max(p1(:,2)) max(p2(:,2))]);
d3 = max([max(p1(:,3)) max(p2(:,3))]);

input1 = [p1(:,1)'/d1; p1(:,2)'/d2; p1(:,3)'/d3];
```

I would like to know what's meant by "d" and "input1" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it up slowly.  Doing `max(p1(:,1))` finds the largest value in the first column of `p1`.  Doing `max(p2(:,1))` finds the largest value in the first column of `p2`.  They will both return a single value.  Next, if you encapsulate a `max` call with these two numbers: `max([max(p1(:,1) max(p2(:,1)]);` this finds the largest value between these two numbers.

Logically speaking, `d1` will find the largest value overall between the first columns of `p1` and `p2` together.  `d2` and `d3` do the same thing but with respect to the second and third columns of `p1` and `p2`.

`input1` I suppose is a crude way of defining input features which belong to the first three columns of `p1` and ensuring that these values fall within the span of `[0,1]` for each column of `p1` individually.  Why they take `p2` into account is unknown to me as they're only doing this for `p1`, but it looks like it's some sort of normalization step that is being performed as a means of pre-processing the input data prior to training.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: "p" is a matrix with 20 rows, and it's divided into two groups, "p1" as an input for the neural network and "p2" as a sample to test the neural network on it and to comapre the results with the target. 

According to the Normalization as you mentioned, the simulated output is supposed to be one column with decimal values, but instead the output become just fractions between (0,1). 
How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Read my answer carefully.... It says that the values fall within the span of 0 and 1. That doesn't mean that they only take on the values of just 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes I understand this point, I meant is it possible to make some mathematical process on the normalized values after training so as to return decimal values close to the target values?